# Pulling Live Data from Excel to Use in my Python Model

Tags: python, excel, api, machine-learning, model

I'm currently working on creating a model that takes as inputs some market data every 30 min of various futures markets. My data provider has a real time data link available for excel so I've set up a spreadsheet to pull all the live values and update live.

I'm ready to start seeing my model make some live predictions so I'm wondering what is the best route to get the data from excel into my python model?

Answer (score -1):

Excel files can be read as csv format.  Here is one example of how to do this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
...     for row in spamreader:
...         print ', '.join(row)
```

Comment: That wont update live and CSV format will require me to lose all my formulas